# How can I map two arrays based on specific indexes?

Tags: php

```
Array1 ( [0] => [1] => [2] => 3 [3] => [4] => 5 [5] => [6] => )
Array2 ( [0] => URD [1] => ISL )
```

I want to map `$array2` values to `$array1` indexes (those having values 3 and 5) and I want get an array like this:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => URD [3] => [4] => ISL [5] => [6] => )
```

I have tried the following:

```
$newArray = array_values(array_filter(array_merge($array1,$array2)));
```

but the actual result is:

```
Array([0] => 3[1] => 5[2] => URD[3] => ISL)
```

The expected result should be:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => URD [3] => [4] => ISL [5] => [6] => )
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [mcve] and [ask]. Show `var_export($array1);var_export($array2);`

Comment: I find this question to be Unclear because there isn't a clear explanation _why_ the elements with 3 and 5 should be replaced  by the values in the other array.  Yes, we can assume that you want to replace non-empty values with the values from the other array, but there appears to be no clear relationship between the second array and the first array values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code**

Try the following:

```
<?php

$array1 = ["", "", "3", "", "5", "", ""];
$array2 = ["URD", "ISL"];

foreach($array1 as $id => $a1){
    //for each item in array 1

    if($a1){
        //if the array 1 item has a value

        $array1[$id] = array_shift($array2);
        //replace it with an item from array 2
    }

    if(empty($array2)){
        //if there are no more values left to share in array 2, stop
        break;
    }
}

var_dump($array1);
```

**Output**

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
  [2]=>
  string(3) "URD"
  [3]=>
  string(0) ""
  [4]=>
  string(3) "ISL"
  [5]=>
  string(0) ""
  [6]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

**Caveats**

The method assumes that there will be values in both array 1 and array 2.

Once the values in array 2 have been split out and array 2 is empty, array 1 items with set values will no longer be affected.

The method does not care *what* the value set in array 1 is, just that there *is* a value.

**Further reading**

[foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

[array_shift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

**Codepen**

https://3v4l.org/RDQY6

Answer (score 0):

This solution works and simple to understands as OPS requested...

```
 <?

    $array1 = ["", "", "3", "", "5", "", ""];
    $array2 = ["URD", "ISL"];

    $i =0;
        foreach($array1 as $keys=>$values) {
            if($values == 3 || $values ==5) {
               if(isset($array2[$i])){
                $array1[$keys] = $array2[$i];
                  $i++;
             }else { break; }
           }
         }
    print_R($array1);
    ?>
```

it will replace the array2 values from array 1 values wherever 5 & 3 will come and which is independent of their sorting order.
example

`$array1 = ["5", "", "3", "", "", "", ""];` will be converted into

```
$array1 = ["URD", "" ,"ISL","","",""];
```

if you want it in order like 3 should always come first then first sort array1 then use my code...
if you want 3 should be replace by URD and 5 should be replace by ISL
then you if codition will be different

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to do it... (untested, but it should work)

```
<?php

$a = array ( 0 => '', 1 => '', 2 => 3, 3 => '', 4 => 5, 5 => '', 6 => '' );

$b = array ( 0 => 'URD', 1 => 'ISL' );

$c = array_replace ( $a, array_combine ( array_keys ( array_filter ( $a ) ), $b ) );

print_r ( $c );

?>
```